# Show that $\{T∈L(R^5,R^4):\dim(\operatorname{null}T)>2\}$ is not a subspace of $L(R^5,R^4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Show that $$\{T∈L(R^5,R^4):\dim(\operatorname{null}T)>2\}$$
is not a subspace of $L(R^5,R^4)$

I'm not sure how to verify this problem, please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you build a rank 4 transformation using rank 1 transformations?

Comment: No, because there isn't enough information from rank 1 to rank 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W= \{T∈L(R^5,R^4):\dim(\operatorname{null}T)>2\}$ and 
define 4 linear transformations $T_i:\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ as follows:

$T_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(x_1,0,0,0).$

$T_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(0,x_2,0,0).$

$T_3(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(0,0,x_3,0).$

$T_4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(0,0,0,x_4).$

Each $T_i \in W.$  However $T_1+T_2+T_3 + T_4$ has rank 4 and is not in $W.$

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer deepens my understanding of properties of vector space and linear maps. Really really appreciate it!!! ^_^